# GAE Standard instance lifetime

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, mongodb-atlas

To try out Google Cloud Platform and Mongodb Atlas, I signed up with both platforms and created a simple app hosted on App Engine Standard that connects to Atlas.

Setting a new timeout after updating, every minute it updates the collection of 5 records, each of which has a name and last_updated field, updating the last_updated field with the current date.

Also, using an Express backend, the app shows the last update date on the appspot url (the GETs in the log below).

After running for about 2 hours, the container was killed by a 9-signal. I was wondering what is the cause of this? 2 hours after it was started? 1 hour after the last front-end call? Why wouldn't it keep running the settimeout / express process?

Memory seemed to be constant (see screens below)

Also, as the CPU log shows, there seemed to be 0 CPU after about 5 minutes while the log shows the exact same output until the shutdown. What is happening there?

Logs:
[image: Logs]

Memory:
[image: Memory]

CPU:
[image: CPU]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For App Engine standard, an instance can either be running or stopped.

Auto scaled services have one or more instances that are always running. Manual or Basic scaled services can be stopped when their is no traffic. You can set the scaling behaviour in app.yaml.

This link will help you understand the lifecycle for App Engine.

[Instance life cycle](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed#instance_life_cycle)

This link documents the app.yaml settings for scaling:

[Scaling elements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements)

Example app.yaml with automatic scaling:

```
service: my-service
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.65
  min_instances: 5
  max_instances: 100
  min_pending_latency: 30ms  # default value
  max_pending_latency: automatic
  max_concurrent_requests: 50
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. As far as I understand, I would need min_instances: 1 for the continuous setTimeout loop to keep running?

Comment: Yes with the limitation that I do not know what your code is doing in the background. The best strategy is for your App Engine application to handle starts, restarts and terminates. App Engine is designed for web based applications that run based upon requests (hitting a web page) that have short lifetimes. For background job based applications App Engine might not be the best choice.

Comment: In addition, for my example I would probably need to seperate the express and setTimeout loop into two different containers, so the first can scale to traffic and the latter be limited to only one instance doing background work. Using min_instances:1 and max_instances: 1 so there won't be multiple background processes?

Comment: Also, hit the Google Cloud pricing calculator to compare costs between GAE and GCE where GAE is always running an instance. https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/

Comment: Close this question as your original problem has been answered. Open new questions on specify issues (one per question).